# Why is SignalR hanging on second instance of localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a problem testing SignalR in a MVC application. Everything works fine with the code posted below, but I found that if I have an error on my localhost application (some logic that fails and throws an exception) I have to stop debbuging, fix the problem and then rebuilding the project to debug again the web application, but after the second time I'm debugging the page never loads, it just appear the spinning loading icon on the tab and never finish loading the page. So I need to close the project and re-open it again. Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
    //Some code and then calling the hub
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<UpdatesHub>();
    context.Clients.All.updateUsers();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

My hub is like this one:

```
[HubName("updateHub")]
public class UpdatesHub : Hub
{
    public void UpdatedUsers()
    {
        Clients.All.updateUsers();
    }
}
```

And javascript:

```
$(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.updateHub;

       //THe method called from MVC for real time update table
        hub.client.updateUsers= function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Home")",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#UserList").html(result);
                }
            });
        }
          $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

My theory is that when I stop debugging the SignalR connection from the hub that I already opened was never closed when I debug the second time and the IIS server can't handle to many connections? I don't know. I found this on github:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3493 but no one is attending the issues and the last release is 1 year old.

Is there a way to stop the connection created from the hub after stop debugging or a specific event like Application_Start() on Global.Asax? Because if I have to use signalR everytime I write some code I'll have to close and re-open the project. I don't know if this issue will affect on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

After searching I found solution here. This solution works for me

[MVC5 hangs on MapSignalR when reconnecting after AppPool cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675939/mvc5-hangs-on-mapsignalr-when-reconnecting-after-apppool-cycles)

Acording to this  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/pull/3609 there will be offical fix to this problem.

I created dummy implementation of Performance Counter and use it instead of standard Performance Counter.

```
// Global.asmx
var tempCounterManager = new TempPerformanceCounterManager();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof (IPerformanceCounterManager), () => tempCounterManager);

[....]

// Helper Class
public class TempPerformanceCounterManager : IPerformanceCounterManager
{
    private readonly static PropertyInfo[] _counterProperties = GetCounterPropertyInfo();
    private readonly static IPerformanceCounter _noOpCounter = new NoOpPerformanceCounter();

    public TempPerformanceCounterManager()
    {
        foreach (var property in _counterProperties)
        {
            property.SetValue(this, new NoOpPerformanceCounter(), null);
        }
    }

    public void Initialize(string instanceName, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken)
    {
    }

    public IPerformanceCounter LoadCounter(string categoryName, string counterName, string instanceName, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        return _noOpCounter;
    }

    internal static PropertyInfo[] GetCounterPropertyInfo()
    {
        return typeof(TempPerformanceCounterManager)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(IPerformanceCounter))
            .ToArray();
    }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsConnected { get; set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsReconnected { get; set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsDisconnected { get; set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsCurrentForeverFrame { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsCurrentLongPolling { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsCurrentServerSentEvents { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsCurrentWebSockets { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionsCurrent { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionMessagesReceivedTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionMessagesSentTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionMessagesReceivedPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ConnectionMessagesSentPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusMessagesReceivedTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusMessagesReceivedPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutMessageBusMessagesReceivedPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusMessagesPublishedTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusMessagesPublishedPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusSubscribersCurrent { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusSubscribersTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusSubscribersPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusAllocatedWorkers { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusBusyWorkers { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter MessageBusTopicsCurrent { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsAllTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsAllPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsHubResolutionTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsHubResolutionPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsHubInvocationTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsHubInvocationPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsTransportTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ErrorsTransportPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutStreamCountTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutStreamCountOpen { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutStreamCountBuffering { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutErrorsTotal { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutErrorsPerSec { get; private set; }
    public IPerformanceCounter ScaleoutSendQueueLength { get; private set; }
}

internal class NoOpPerformanceCounter : IPerformanceCounter
{
    public string CounterName
    {
        get
        {
            return GetType().Name;
        }
    }
    public long Decrement()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public long Increment()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public long IncrementBy(long value)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public long RawValue
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
    public void Close()
    {
    }
    public void RemoveInstance()
    {
    }
    public CounterSample NextSample()
    {
        return CounterSample.Empty;
    }
}
```