# Asp.net mvc web page won't load after build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015

In Visual studio 2015 Update 3 after building Web project it won't load in web browser and no timeout is happening, the browsers loading spinner is active.
Only IIS app pool recycle helps to load web page successfully. This issue is known on more than one project.

I had installed Visual Studio 2017 RC and i think that it is the culprit. Removing VS2017 RC did not help.

What possible actions can i take to try to solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Moe still having the same problem with Visual Studio 2017. Just restarting app pool for now. But now it from time to time loads web page without need of app pool recycle. IIS shows that problem may be on web page load actions.

Comment: Having the same problem as well! It's strange.. Thanks for getting to me.

Comment: @Moe try my answer if you're still having the same problem.

Comment: I will! Thanks man

Comment: Finally I found out my problem! It was the Ninject DI container. I didn't find a solution yet, but I removed it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in PerformanceCounters when creating MemoryCache in 3rd party library (MvcSiteMapProvider). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33813225/841467) helped a lot. And an [in depth problem description](https://www.zpqrtbnk.net/posts/appdomains-threads-cultureinfos-and-paracetamol) with solution.